# Migrate Room database with Autoincrement Primary Key

Tags: android, sql, android-room, migrate

I have an Entity User that creates UID automatically upon save to db.

I'm trying to migrate the table but the old UID of the users don't migrate which is a serious problem.

How can I keep the old UID?

```
 ContentValues cv = null;
            try {
                Cursor c = database.query("SELECT * FROM users");
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    cv = new ContentValues();
                    do {
                        cv.put("uid", c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("uid")));
                        cv.put("name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));                       
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.ex(TAG, ex);
            }

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'users'");
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`uid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    "`name` TEXT)");

            if (cv != null)
                database.insert("users", 0, cv);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are at best only saving 1 row.

Using the above you would want an Array of ContentValue's to save multiple users.

e.g.

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> cvlist = new ArrayList<>();

Cursor c = database.query("SELECT * FROM users");
while(c.moveToNext) {
    ContentValue cv = new ContentValue();
    cv.put("uid",c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("uid")));
    cv.put("name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
    cvlist.add(cv);
}

database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'users'");
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`uid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                "`name` TEXT)");
for(ContentValue cv: cvlist) {
    database.insert("users", 0, cv);
}
```

---

**However**, you could simplify the above by using :-

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_users` (`uid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
            "`name` TEXT)");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `temp_users` SELECT * FROM `users`");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `users` RENAME TO `original_users`");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `temp_users` RENAME TO `users`");
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `original_users`");
```

This creates the new table with a different name (temp_users), copies all the rows from the original table into the new table. It then renames the original table, and then renames the new table to the actual name (so now becomes the actual tables that it used) and finally drops the renamed original table.

(you could just drop the original table instead of altering it's name, however the above is safer).

- **Note** the above is in-principle code, it has not been run or tested and may therefore contains some errors.

Comment: Amazing method. Before you answered I already seen the bug in my code and did the same as you suggested in #1. But your #2 method blew my mind. Thanks!

Comment: 1 Question- Will this work if the new table has columns the old one does not?

Comment: @ntwired33 perhaps the new columns would be populated with the default value, which via an entity cannot be defined so would be null, and may result in a NOT NULL constraint conflict depedning upon the Entity (e.g if a java primary type (implicit NOT NULL or if @NonNull is coded)). Saying that you could adapt by using something like (assuming adding a column and that 'x' is a suitable default) by using `INSERT INTO temp_users SELECT *,'x' FROM users`

Comment: @ntwired33 you can also code specific columns for both tables (number of columns must match) e.g. if the name column were removed you could use `INSERT INTO temp_users (uid) SELECT uid FROM users`